# How to add to the titlebar right click menu in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, window

I can add a context menu to the body of my widget, but how to handle the title bar right click?

I'm using PyQt

Answer (score 0):

building on this but in python:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/45489/solved-add-custom-actions-for-menu-shown-upon-clicking-the-title-bar-icon/3

```py
import win32con
import win32gui
import logging

custom_menu_id = 100

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, manager, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        hwnd = self.winId()
        hmenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, False)
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_SEPARATOR, 0, '')
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_STRING, custom_menu_id, 'Custom menu text')

    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        # handle the click on the title bar
        try:
            msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        except:
            logging.error("", exc_info=True)

        if eventType == "windows_generic_MSG":
            if msg.message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
                # bonus - here's how to handle the left click
                pass

            if msg.message == WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                if msg.wParam == custom_menu_id:
                   # do me now!
                   pass
```